# Changing nouns into adjectives

Tags: прилагательные, существительные

How can I change nouns into adjectives? 
Ветер → Ветреный

Comment: There are dozens of patterns how an adjective can be derived from a noun, also, for obvious reasons, a single noun can produce different adjectives that are constructed different way.  This is way too broad and just can not have a single accepted answer - a reasonably short one.

Comment: BTW you can build more than one adjective from a noun. For ветер it's not only ветреный, but also ветровой.

Comment: @Abakan as well as at least `ветренный`, `ветряной` and even `ветряный`

Comment: The most generic (and the most productive) suffix is -ский: Москва - московский, банк - банковский, дети - детский. There might be other suffixes in front of -ский, e.g. Сидней can be both сиднейский and сиднеевский (less formal). Перу -  перуанский. To find out the exact suffix, use http://morpher.ru/adjectivizer

Comment: I think it's a fair question that deserves a direct answer (which might be long).

Comment: @SergeySlepov you can vote to reopen it, with enough votes for re-open, it will happen automatically, but the answer wont' be just long - it would be enormous.

Comment: @SergeySlepov -ский only works for adjectives of belonging (not sure about proper name), then there is -овый for being made of something and much more suffixes for different types of adjectives. But this is indeed a fair and interesting question.